# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ValueObjectLayer.booksVAL>' to 'int'

Tags: c#, winforms, layered

I'm trying to make a 3 layered C# Library Management project.

I'm trying to select a book from bookDAL (dataacceslayer) through booksBLL(businesslogiclayer and show it on winforms.

i get this error message on BLL
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZqpS.png)

DAL:

```
    public static List<booksVAL> BookSelect(string x)
    {
        List<booksVAL> sonuc = new List<booksVAL>();
        OleDbCommand cmdkitaplistele = new OleDbCommand("select * from books where id = " + Int32.Parse(x) + " ", dbConnection.conn); // 
        if (cmdkitaplistele.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open) // bağlantı açık değise
        {
            cmdkitaplistele.Connection.Open(); // bağlantıyı aç
        }

        OleDbDataReader dr = cmdkitaplistele.ExecuteReader(); // sorgu sonuçlarını data reader ile oku
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            booksVAL book = new booksVAL();
            book.bookId = int.Parse(dr["id"].ToString());
            book.bookName = dr["bookname"].ToString();
            book.bookAuthor = dr["authorname"].ToString();
            book.bookPagecount = dr["pagecount"].ToString();
            book.bookDatepublished = dr["datepublished"].ToString();
            book.bookIsavailable = dr["isavailable"].ToString();
            book.bookCategory = dr["category"].ToString();
            sonuc.Add(book);
        }
        dr.Close();
        return sonuc;
    }
```

BLL:

```
public static int BookSelect(string x)
{
    return booksDAL.BookSelect(x);
```

Form:

```
public partial class bookupdateForm : Form
{
   booksForm f1;
    public bookupdateForm(booksForm frm1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.f1 = frm1;
        booksBLL.BookSelect(f1.selectedlabel.Text); // selectedlabel comes from another form, it works

    }
}
```

Comment: `return booksDAL.BookSelect(x)` returns a `List`, but you're calling it in `public static int BookSelect(string x)` and trying to return the list, rather than an `int`.

Comment: Please don't use string concatination to create an sql query, use parameterized statements. Learn how to mitigate sql injection attacks.

Comment: I bet if you double-click that error, it will bring you to the offending line (you can also look at the _Output_ pane and see the associated line number). That might have been enough for you to see the error. If not, you could have included that information in your question and made our job much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
public static int BookSelect(string x)
{
    return booksDAL.BookSelect(x);
}
```

Change return type `int` to `List<booksVAL>`:

```
public static List<booksVAL> BookSelect(string x)
{
    return booksDAL.BookSelect(x);
}
```